# Scala - Timer Error

Tags: scala, junit

I'm new on Scala and I'm trying to pass a function/method as parameter to another by using unit, but it gives me the following error:

```
Timer.<error: >
```

My code is the following:

```
object Timer {
  def oncePerSecond(callback: () => unit) {
    while (true) {
      callback(); Thread sleep 1000
    }
  }
  def timeFlies() {
    println("The time passes...")
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    oncePerSecond(timeFlies)
  }
}
```

But I'm certainly my code is correct and I don't understand why I'm getting this. Can someone help me to find this bug?

The error seems to be in the word "unit" on line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unit` with a capital U fixes the error. Classes in Scala begin with a capital letter.

Comment: "Classes in Scala begin with a capital letter"—only by convention, and I wouldn't be surprised if there were exceptions even in the standard library. "Primitive type names begin with a capital letter" is probably more helpful.